How to describe a dataset that most observations are close to right boundary?
I have a data set $(x, y)$, where $x\geq 0$ is time in minutes, $y\geq 0$ is score in points. Most $x$ values ​​are close to the right boundary (figure).
Question. How to describe a relationship $y=f(x)$? Only by scatterplot?
It is obvious that my attempt to use a linear regression (red line) is not working.


What is the meaning of this boundary? Can this be expressed as some kind of fraction instead?

$x$ is time in minutes, $y$ is score in point.

As long as you don't do a standard analysis that assumes equal variance across X and linearity in X vs. Y you should be OK.

you may have a capped $x$: $y=f(s)\x=max(s_{max},s)$. if this is the case, then you estimate both $f()$ and $s\ge s_{max}$

You could call this censored data. A typical such dataset (is it the OP's case?) is for "time to complete an exam" vs "score on the exam". Most students will wait till the last minute(s) to submit. But it does not mean that they did not complete the exam (much?) earlier; they just used the extra time to double-check, refine the answers, etc. So interpreting the fact that students hiy the time limit is ambiguous at best...

You say your linear regression “obviously” doesn’t work. Why do you say that? Your rationale this claim will be informative. $//$ Remember that you are considering conditional expected values and distributions in regression, so there is a sense in which the distributions of $x$ does not matter.

@jginestet is 'cenosred' the right term here? in your examples censored would be students who didn't submit on time, and excluded from data set.

As you (presumably) can't have negative time, I'd try to predict the score as a function of (say) the logarithm of the time.  I'd normalise the scores to lie between 0 and 1, and perhaps use beta regression where the parameters of the beta distribution for the conditional probability of the score are functions of log time.  IIRC Beta distributions are a reasonable starting point for proportions. Alternatively you could look at quantile regression of the scores as a function of log time.

Log-transform or power law transform of the distance from the boundary might improve the situation - but it is better to use the transformation suggested by the nature of the problem (if possible.)
